# iPhone - Flip animation when navigation controller popped

Tags: ios, iphone

How to Flip animation when navigation is controller popped, how we can achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code for the flip animation for pop view

```
[UIView  beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0.375];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Following code for the Animation Block

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75
                         animations:^{
                             [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
                             [UIView setAnimationTransition:transition forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
                         }];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Below Code to Push your View to next view.

```
-(IBAction)gotonextView:(id)sender
{
NextView *info = [[NextView alloc]initWithNibName:@"NextView" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController * nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:info];

        info.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:nvc animated:YES];

}
```

Automatically You will get the same flip animation while popping out.